# Find the rank of matrix.

Tags: matrices

"Find rank of matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
                    0&0&-3\\ 
                    9&3&5\\
                    3&1&1\\
                    \end{bmatrix}$
using echelon form?"
"I am getting an answer equal to 2."

"When I reduce this I get $\begin{bmatrix}
                          1&1/3&0\\
                          0&0&1\\
                           0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}$ so two pivots so rank must me 2 right ? However the book I am using says rank =1."

Comment: Your question is not clear ; it is impossible understanding what is your matrix and what you've tried just by reading your question!

Comment: The reason people cannot read your question is because you did not use LaTeX. Please google for StackExchange LaTeX guide.

Comment: I have edited the question to add LaTeX.. I guess it is a $3\times 3$ matrix from what the raw code is about.

Comment: @Vivek why exactly do you used quotation marks (that is,  `"..."`)?  Can we just get rid of them?

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a rank 2 matrix.
$\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&-3\\
9&3&5\\
3&1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}\overset{r_1\leftrightarrow r_3}{\rightarrow}
\begin{bmatrix}
3&1&1\\
9&3&5\\
0&0&-3\\
\end{bmatrix}
\overset{r_2=r_2-3\times r_1}{\rightarrow}
\begin{bmatrix}
3&1&1\\
0&0&2\\
0&0&-3\\
\end{bmatrix}
\overset{r_3=r_3+\frac{3}{2}\times r_2}{\rightarrow}
\begin{bmatrix}
3&1&1\\
0&0&2\\
0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\overset{r_1=r_1/3}{\rightarrow}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}\\
0&0&2\\
0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\overset{r_2=r_2/2}{\rightarrow}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\overset{r_1=r_1-r_2/3}{\rightarrow}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&\frac{1}{3}&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Your book has made a mistake.

P.S. Welcome to Math.SE! Next time please learn to use some basic MathJaX to prevent people from downvoting you and misunderstanding you. You may start from [this tutorial on Math.SE.Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Which matrix have you considered ? Also, an answer may provide some details.

Comment: $3\times 3$ matrix. The question fails to use correct format but it can be seen in raw code.

Comment: Vivek Chawla must confirm this now. Anyway, it should be fine if you edited your answer by writing explicitly the matrix and by explaining how you got the rank equals to $2$.

Comment: The question has been edited correctly. Sorry people i am using this site for the first or second time I didn't know about latex ! But the thanks to the guy for correcting the question and the answer is 2 right ?

Comment: @VivekChawla If you are satisfied with this answer, you can validate it and even vote up.

Comment: @nicolas i dis upvote the answer confirming my answer is correct and the problem is within the book !

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Next time please learn some basic LaTeX since you need it when you are going to publish a paper or write your CV anyway. Sorry but it is hard to not be misunderstood (and downvoted) if you do not use LaTeX to type math correctly.

Comment: @Nicolas I was having a meal..Now I will edit it..

Comment: @YingZhou And now it is a good and useful answer. +1